# Php for HTML form

Tags: php, html, forms, submit, registration

I have the html for a registration and was wondering how you might structure a php to say thank you for registering after submission, Hope this is not to broad a question.

HTML:

```
<body bgcolor="black" style="color:white;">
<FORM ACTION="register.php" METHOD=get>
<h1>REGISTRATION</h1>
please input the registration details to create an account here and attend future     events<br>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>First Name:</td><td><input name="regname" type="text" size"20"></input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Last Name:</td><td><input name="regname" type="text" size"20"></input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>D.O.B:</td><td><input name="regname" type="text" size"20"></input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email:</td><td><input name="regname" type="text" size"20"></input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Address:</td><td><input name="regname" type="text" size"20"></input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Postcode :</td><td><input name="regemail" type="text" size"20"></input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password :</td><td><input name="regpass1" type="password" size"20"></input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Retype Password :</td><td><input name="regpass2" type="password" size"20"></input></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="register me!"></input>
</FORM>
```

Thank you

Comment: I'm afraid it is a *little* too broad. Do you not have any PHP code of your own to provide?

Comment: On your `register.php` Add this code.. `<?php echo("Thank you for registering");`

Comment: first you need learn PHP tutorial then you get idea.. http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php

Comment: Thank you I will have a look at it!

Answer (score 0):

That's not a big deal to write message for "thank you for registering".

I think you are using PHP code to submit your form. Where you can process with the PHP coding to inserting user record (who are going to be registerd) in database. at that time do following steps.
1) just check it out that is your data inserted into database or any error is there?
2) If your data is inserted to the table, store message in any variable.
3) pass on that variable to the next page with URL or as hidden variable.
4) check on that page, is that variable is set or not, if yes just print that one. else leave that portion as blank.

Answer (score 0):

Your Form action is on "register.php".

1) Simply after your query execution (insert query to DB) write a code, for example:

```
$query = mysql_query(" INSERT QUERY..");
if($query)
  echo "Thank You for registration";
```

2) you can redirect to some thankyou.php page.

3) You can set message variable or session variable and display that in header.

And please you method="post" in your form. Get is not a secured method as this will display all information in query string(in URL).

Thanks!

Comment: it should be `mysql_query`.. @Reetika